# Need Helping Editing Perl Script for PowerChute Network Shutdown

Tags: perl, apc

I found the perl script on the vmware community. The problem is that within APC's PCNS it will not let you specify parameters to run with the script.

The script requires calling on a host-list file  Usage: ./shutdownHostViaSOAPAPICall.pl [HOST_FILE]

So I would like to add the hosts I want to shutdown directly into the script instead of having to call a hostlist file.

Can anyone help with this? Here is the Vsphere thread for reference. And so that you can download the script.

https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-11623

Thanks

Comment: why would you want to do this?  the current mode it works in allows you to manage the file without threat of breaking the code - adding the hosts directly and managing new/old host adds and removals introduces new opportunities to blow stuff up

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should include the code in your question, along with a specific problem and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving the problem yourself. See: [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Paul Allen PCNS only lets you specify the script location and does not let you run it with any switches/parameters/modifiers etc. That's why I would like it all in one file. I was able to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
my $host_username = 'fillmein';
my $host_password = 'fillmein';

#### DO NOT EDIT PAST HERE ####

my @hostlist;
my ($file,$request,$message,$response,$retval,$cookie);

&verifyUserInput();
&processFile($file);
```

With

```
my $host_username = 'yourusername';
my $host_password = 'yourpass';

#### DO NOT EDIT PAST HERE ####

my @hostlist = ("host1.somedomain", ""hostx.somedomain"");
my ($file,$request,$message,$response,$retval,$cookie);

#&verifyUserInput();
#&processFile($file);
```

I only have 1 host at each site to shut down so this is a clean solution for me.

Comment: The `""hostx.somedomain""` part will cause a syntax error.